# Extracting a numeric value from multiple filename in R

Tags: r, regex, csv, filenames

I'm trying to extract a numeric value from multiple filenames, for instance I have filenames such as **abc_2.csv; pow_4.csv; foo_5.csv**...so on, I 'm trying to extract only the last numeric value from file name. I have tried extracting for one file at a time but want to do it as altogether,this is what I have tried for a

> single file

```
>nop <- basename("D:/files/abc_2.csv")
>nop <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", nop))
>nop
  2
```

> for multiple files

```
setwd("D:/files")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: your "single file" code and "multiple file" code are not remotely attempting to do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
regmatches(t, regexpr( "\\d+", t))
#[1] "2" "4" "5"
```

If it is the last number to extract

```
sub(".*(\\d+)\\D+$", "\\1", t)
```

or

```
sapply(regmatches(t, gregexpr( "\\d+", t)), tail, 1)
```

#### data

```
t <- c("abc_2.csv","pow_4.csv","foo_5.csv")
```

Comment: Actually this solution returns only the *first* numeric value in the string rather than the *last* as required in question statement. 
Try data `t <- c("asdf_1_2.csv", "asdf_3_4.csv")`.

Comment: @TurtleIzzy  That we can do with `sub` i.e. `sub(".*(\\d+)\\D+$", "\\1", t)#
[1] "2" "4"` or with the other solution `sapply(regmatches(t, gregexpr( "\\d+", t)), tail, 1)#
[1] "2" "4"`

Comment: That actually solves the problem with minor modification. `sub(".*?(\\d+)\\D+$", "\\1", t)` works.

Comment: I didn't, i don't think that was me.

Comment: @TurtleIzzy  Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

You need `stri_extract_last(...)` from library `stringi`.

```
library('stringi')
t = c("abc_2.csv","pow_4.csv","foo_5.csv")

stri_extract_last(t, regex = "(\\d+)")
```

Answer (score 1):

just extending your solution :

```
setwd("D:/location")
temp = list.files(pattern=".*_\\d+.csv") # this will ensure only the selective files(with the specified pattern) are chosen, and not all the files in directory
unlist(lapply(temp, function(x) gsub( "(.*_|\\.csv)", "", x)))
#[1] "2" "4" "5"
```